# NServiceBus, why can I Bus.Send, but not Bus.Publish? Need help debugging

Tags: windows-server-2008, msmq, nservicebus, publish-subscribe

Ok,

### Quick background

1. We're using NServiceBus 2.0 with pretty much the standard config, nothing "crazy" going on.
2. App is .NET 3.5
3. Dev environment is Publisher and Subscriber are on the same box, Windows 7.
4. Staging environment is Publisher and Subscriber are on different boxes, one Windows 7, the other Windows Server 2008.

### Behaviour

- On the Dev environment, Publisher Subscriber work fine, which suggests the code itself is ok in term on Starting Up, Configuring Containers etc, and all the messages being configured correctly, i.e size, serialization etc.
- On the Staging environment, the Publisher SUCCESSFULLY receives the subscription request.
- It also successfully stores the subscriber in the Subscription table (SQL Server, we're using DBSubscription), and the "queuename@machinename" is correct.

## Problem

On Bus.Publish() nothing happens. No Outgoing Queue is created, no message sent or created anywhere, no error is thrown.

### Extra Info

- Interestingly a Bus.Send from the Publisher works fine! except of course I have to add this to the config:

  <UnicastBusConfig>
      <MessageEndpointMappings>
          <add Messages="Library.Messages" Endpoint="subscriberqueue@machinename"/>
      </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
- Also the Publisher CAN resolve:

> ping machinename

SO, what's going on, and what should I be looking out for?

Why does SEND work, and PUBLISH doesn't?

How can I get PUBLISH working?

Answer (score 0):

Turn the logging threshold to debug and see if the publisher logs "sending message to..." during the call to publish.